# Mysql error while updating data using perl language

Tags: mysql, perl

## Update function

I am getting an error while updating data from database.

```
  sub update
    {
        my $sql = "UPDATE Data SET NAME = ?, ADDRESS=?, PHONE_NO=?, 
        DATE_OF_JOINING=?, ROLE_ASSIGN=?, SALARY=? WHERE ID = ?";

        my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

        print("Enter ID to update : ");
              chomp(my $ID = <STDIN>);

        print("NAME            : ");
        chomp(my $NAME = <STDIN>);

        print("ADDRESS         : ");
        chomp(my $ADDRESS = <STDIN>);

        print("PHONE_NO        : ");
        chomp(my $PHONE_NO = <STDIN>);

        print("DATE_OF_JOINING : ");
        chomp(my $DATE_OF_JOINING = <STDIN>);

        print("ROLE_ASSIGN     : ");
        chomp(my $ROLE_ASSIGN = <STDIN>);

        print("SALARY          : ");
        chomp(my $SALARY = <STDIN>);

        $sth->bind_param(1,$NAME);
        $sth->bind_param(2,$ADDRESS);
        $sth->bind_param(3,$PHONE_NO);
        $sth->bind_param(4,$DATE_OF_JOINING);
        $sth->bind_param(5,$ROLE_ASSIGN);
        $sth->bind_param(6,$SALARY);
        $sth->bind_param(7,$ID);

        $sth->execute();

         print("The record has been updated successfully!");

        $sth->finish();
        $dbh->disconnect();
        }
```

## After executing above function when i try to view updated data :

```
   sub query_links
    {    

      my ($dbh) = @_;
      my $sql = "SELECT * FROM Data";

      my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die $DBI::errstr;

      $sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr; 

      $sth->dump_results();

      $sth->finish();
    }
```

## Error:

```
 DBD::mysql::st execute failed: MySQL server has gone away at mini.plx line 94,

 <STDIN> line 9.MySQL server has gone away
```

Comment: Did you reconnect after doing `$dbh->disconnect();`???

Comment: Please make a more minimal example that still produces the same error.

Answer (score 2):

The error message means that the connection to your database has been lost.

You don't show us any code that creates your connection, so it's hard to know what might have gone wrong there. You might consider adding the `mysql_auto_reconnect` flag when connecting to the database.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password, {
   mysql_auto_reconnect => 1,
});
```

You can also change this setting after the database connection has been set up.

```
$dbh->{mysql_auto_reconnect} = 1;
```

**Update:** As ikegami points out in a comment, you disconnect from the database at the end of `update()` - and you don't show any code demonstrating that you reconnect before using the connection again in `query_links()`. That will cause this problem.

Comment: Thanks as ikegami said i wasn't reconnecting that caused the problem.